# Type of Probability Distribution

Tags: probability

A lottery consists of picking 5 numbers from 1 to 46, the winner of this lottery has to match all numbers chosen. That is, his/her 5 numbers have to match the 5 numbers taken from 1 to 46.

A player of this lottery is to count how many of his/her numbers match the winning 5-number combination.

**Would this be a hypergeometric distribution?**

Comment: Yes, the number of matches follows a hypergeometric distribution, provided that the numbers are equally likely to be chosen and there are no repetition.

Comment: Better than a 50-50 chance to match one number, less than 1 chance in a million to match all 5.